# Unix Organizing Script

Tags: bash

So I'm in a summer Intro Unix course right now and we need to write a script that organizes files into directories based on file extension. Right now I'm getting a syntax error that I can't seem to find. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Are you sure you want to reorganize your files? (Y to continue)"
read response

if [ $response == "Y" ]  ; then 

    echo "Organizing files!"
    touch organize.log
    echo "Organizing..." > organize.log

    mkdir music
    mkdir video
    mkdir text

    for filename in *
    do
        extension="${filename##*.}"

    if [ extension == "mp3" ] || [ extension == "oog" ] || [ extension == "wav" ] ; then

            echo "$filename --> music/$filename" > organize.log
            mv $file music 

    elif [ extension == "wmv" ] || [ extension == "mov" ] || [ extension == "mpg" ] ; then

        echo "$filename --> video/$filename" > organize.log
        mv $file video 

    elif [ extension == "txt" ] ; then

        echo "$filename --> text/$filename" > organize.log
        mv $file text

    done

    echo "Finished organizing files!"
    echo "Bye!"

else
    echo "Ok then. Bye."
    exit

fi

exit
```

I'm new to Unix so I'm finding this pretty hard. If anyone can give me any tips I'd be greatly appreciative.

Here is the new error:

```
organizefiles.sh: line 38: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
organizefiles.sh: line 38: `    done    '
```

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not an appropriate place to ask people to debug your script. The question is unlikely to be able to help anyone else searching for answers. Also, changing the question as people answer to remove the errors they point out invalidates their answer. The logical conclusion to this activity is to end up with a post saying "Hey, look at my script with no errors".

Comment: I would think stackoverflow is the best place to ask people to help debug code and script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is malformed.

```
for ...
do
   ...
done
```

**EDIT:**

`if` needs `fi`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more concise version of your script

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Are you sure you want to reorganize your files? (Y to continue) " response
if [[ $response != [Yy]* ]]  ; then 
    echo "Ok then. Bye."
    exit
fi

echo "Organizing files!"
# don't need "touch", the file will be created if it doesn't exist.
echo "Organizing..." > organize.log

# use "-p" to avoid errors if the dirs already exist
mkdir -p music video text

# Don't Repeat Yourself, use a function
function moveto {
    echo "$2 --> $1/$2" >> organize.log
    mv "$2" "$1"
}

for filename in *
do
    case "${filename##*.}" in 
        mp3|ogg|wav) moveto music "$filename" ;;
        wmv|mov|mpg) moveto video "$filename" ;;
        txt)         moveto text  "$filename" ;;
    esac
done

echo "Finished organizing files!"
echo "Bye!"
```

Comment: Wow thanks, this is great. I'm new to Unix so my scripts are generally convoluted